# ImportError: cannot import name 'is_string_like' from 'matplotlib.cbook

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
    <ipython-input-8-8ef302d419f0> in <module>
      1 from netCDF4 import Dataset
      2 import numpy
----> 3 from SkewTplus.sounding import sounding

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\SkewTplus\sounding.py in <module>
     19 
     20 from SkewTplus.`enter code here`errorHandling import fatalError
---> 21 from SkewTplus.skewT import figure
     22 
     23 

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\SkewTplus\skewT.py in <module>
     23 from matplotlib.axes import Axes
     24 from matplotlib.backends import pylab_setup
---> 25 from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like
     26 from matplotlib.figure import Figure
     27 from matplotlib.projections import register_projection

    ImportError: cannot import name 'is_string_like' from 'matplotlib.cbook' 
    (C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py)
```

I got an error when I import `SkewTplus`. I don't know what to do. I have tried reinstalling `matplotlib` but the problem doesn't go away.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling SkewTplus?

Comment: This function was deprecated and has been removed in newer versions of matplotlib. You have to adapt your code or downgrade the library.

Comment: @BenT, yes, I have. but, it's doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error and solved it by reinstalling it again.Make sure using conda and pip to reinstall the package and then reinstall it again.

```html
pip uninstall matplotlib
conda uninstall matplotlib
```